# Editing an email which is part of a live journey

Tags: journeybuilder

I'm new to the Journey Builder and I'm just wondering whether there is any difference between editing an email in the Content Builder or editing it in a live journey itself.

Previous my colleagues have been editing our emails in the Content Builder, which I understand would update the content in a journey itself.

Is there any reason why I would need to edit the email in the journey itself as opposed to the Content Builder?

Thank you,
Maria

Answer (score 0):

Editing the content in Content Builder will not update the content in live journey. It will update in a non live (draft) journey. An ideal approach is to edit the content in content builder and refresh the email activity using [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5) method

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the email in the live journey, it will **[update the journey immediately](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_multiple_journey_builder_emails.htm&type=5)** to use that new content. This is replacing the **[previous requirement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5)** of pausing, republishing and then restarting a trigger each time content was updated (like you still need to do on normal triggered sends).

This was a great feature that JB has to help you save time and remove the confusion around this process. BUT it does not work if you edit in Content Builder and not in the live journey. Any changes to emails outside of the live journey they are in, will not result in the content being automatically updated. It will just change the email in content builder.

Each Journey or Email Send automatically creates a snapshot of the email (with pre-rendering to allow for quicker execution) at schedule/publish and this is not updated unless the send is either cancelled and rebuilt or paused/republished (which is automatically done in JB when you edit in there).

Comment: Thank you for your help. For some reason when I hover over the email in the Journey, as per the tutorial, there is nothing that I can click to edit it. Do you have any suggestions by any chance?